# How to I replicate this using tcolorbox?

Tags: tcolorbox

[image]

I am trying but I am just unable to get this kind of box.

```tex
\newtcolorbox{defn}[1][]{
    width=\textwidth,
    colback=white!20,
    colframe=blue!75!blue,
    colbacktitle=blue!85!blue,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    left=2ex,
    right=2ex,
    top=2pt,
    arc=2pt,
    outer arc=0pt,
    leftrule=1pt,
    rightrule=1pt,
    toprule=1pt,
    bottomrule=1pt,
    breakable,
    enhanced jigsaw,
    title= #1}
```

This gives me something like this:
[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Just so we don't suggest something you've already tried.

Comment: @Plergux check the edits.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @ThaqibDamani2.0 colframe and colbacktitle is where you define the colour of the text box and the frame. As you can see it is set to a variant of blue. You could try changing those two to orange for a start. Also, "enhanced jigsaw" is a specific tcolorbox theme. If I remember correctly you could do "enhanced.title" instead and "attach boxed title top left". But without having more to work with that's about all I can suggest at the moment.

Comment: @Plergux can you give an example please, I am new to LaTeX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `\newtcbtheorem` in combination with a boxed title, you can achieve the following output in which the boxes are numbered automatically. You can also use the usual label-ref-mechanism on these boxes.

I have also tried to simplify the other options by summarizing `leftrule=1pt, rightrule=1pt, toprule=1pt,bottomrule=1pt,` to `boxrule=1pt`. I have also replaced the corner related options with `sharp corners` since the corners in your example image seemed to nor be rounded. If you prefer the slightly rounded look, you can easily revert the changes.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbtheorem{defn}{Definition}{
    width=\textwidth,
    colback=white!20,
    colframe=orange,
    colbacktitle=orange,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    sharp corners,
    boxrule=1pt,
    breakable,
    enhanced,
    boxed title style={sharp corners},
    attach boxed title to top left
}{def}
    
    
\begin{document}

\begin{defn}{box title}{label}
contents
\end{defn}

\ref{def:label}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example on how you can reproduce the image using `tcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum,lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%
\definecolor{newcolor}{RGB}{246,164,4} % 
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,title=Definition 1: Set,
colframe=newcolor,arc=0mm, fonttitle=\bfseries,coltitle=white,
attach boxed title to top left={xshift=0.mm,yshift=-0.50mm},
boxed title style={skin=enhancedfirst jigsaw,size=small,arc=0mm,bottom=0mm,
interior style={fill=newcolor}}]
\begin{itemize}
 \item[$\bullet$] A \emph{set} is a collection of object.
 \item[$\bullet$] These objects are called \emph{elements} of the set.
 \item[$\bullet$] If $A$ is a set and $x$ is an element of $A$, write $x\in A$.
 \item[$\bullet$] If $x$ is not an element of $A$, write $A\not\in A$.
\end{itemize}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `leftmargin` from `enumitem` package can be used to adjust the left margin that  seems to be too wide. :-)

Comment: To match it with the image posted by OP, I kept the leftmargins wide.