# How can I change the title position in declaretheoremstyle?

Tags: newtheorem

How can I make the following box using declaretheoremstyle?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! [This older answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/566253/134144) might serve as a starting point.

Comment: i can do using tcolorbox. But I want to do use declaretheorem. Is it possible?

Comment: What's the reason for not wanting to use `tcolorbox`?

Comment: I have not reason, I want to do the box another way if it is possible.

Comment: If it is possible and I will learn this way, then I do box by many ways and I can teach to students about possible ways.

Comment: There are other packages such as `mdframed` that can help with boxes around theorems (see for example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/233932/134144), but `tcolorbox` is a lot more flexible.